# nearby location Google API without using google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In my app  I m not using google map.But I am using Google'e geocoding & reverse geocoding API.
I guess these API does not require to create project in google project console..
 now I need an API which can give me nearby places result accepting lat,long and search string as input parameters.
there is an autocomplete API , this is only I want but I think it requires to use g-maps only.

Is there any API that I can use without creating project and just with the key.

Comment: This question is confusing. I am not really sure what you are asking for but I have used the Google's geocoding and reverse geocoding APIs. Are you looking for an API that you hit with a lat, lng, keyword that will return a list of nearby places? Can you provide an example to clear up your question?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I am not sure exactly what you are after but have you tried the google [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en) Api?